# How can I manipulate contents of an extjs panel as I can a DOM element?

Tags: extjs

In the following extJS page, when I click the button, the content of the HTML Div "buttonInfo" changes correctly.

I want to also change the contents of the panel that I created with extJS.

However, when I change the contents of the panel as I do the div, the whole panel is simply replaced.

**How can I change the contents of my panel object from within my button's click handler?**

## before:

[image]

## after:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 20px;
            }
            div#infoBox {
                margin: 10px 0 0 0;
                width: 190px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: lightblue;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            div#content {
                margin: 10px 0 0 0;
            }
            div.x-panel-body {
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <title>Simple extJS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'ext/resources/images/default/s.gif';
            Ext.onReady(function(){

                Ext.get('buttonInfo').on('click', function(){
                    Ext.get('infoBox').update('This is the <b>new</b> content.');
                    Ext.get('panel1').update('new info');
                    //Ext.get('panel1').html = 'new info111'; //doesn't work
                    //panel1.html = 'new info222'; //doesn't work
                });

                new Ext.Panel({
                    id: 'panel1',
                    renderTo: 'content',
                    width: '210px',
                    title: 'Extended Info',
                    html: 'original text',
                    collapsible: true
                });

            });            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="buttonInfo">
            Show Info
        </button>
        <div id="infoBox">
        </div>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </body
```

>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ext.get gives you the dom object, use Ext.getCmp instead so that it returns the Ext object back, then you can use the update method on the panel:

Try:

Ext.getCmp('panel1').update('new info');

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you have firebug installed then you can easily see the difference.

Comment: thanks that's the method I was looking for, and I have the object so I can do things like this: Ext.getCmp('infoBox2').setWidth(333);

Comment: Keep in mind that update is not just a plain innerHTML wrapper of some sort, it is updating the data used by the Layout specified on your component, therefore you may need to call doLayout(); after the call to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`var Data = 'new info';
panel1.overwrite(panel1.body, Data);
panel1.doComponentLayout();`

Comment: If don't running on your script, only alternative is some:
`Ext.getCmp('panel1').update('new info');`